# groupby and remove lowest value in r dataframe

Tags: r, group-by, duplicates

I essentially want to drop duplicates from a dataframe and keep the lowest value in a column, grouped by two columns (Name and cluster).  For instance, here if my dataframe:

```
       Name   cluster   score
19     Steve   a1       30
51     Steve   a2       30
83     Steve   a2      -28
93     Steve   a2      -38
115    Bob     a4       30
147    Bob     a5       -8
179    Bob     a5       30
```

in pandas and sql this would be done by a groupby but i'm struggling to figure it out in R and really even get started.  I tried doing a double sort of Name and cluster.  the first groupby is Name and then cluster.  So since there are three 'Steve, a2' i only want to keep the one with the lowest score.

My desired output would be the following:

```
       Name   cluster   score
19     Steve   a1       30
93     Steve   a2      -38
115    Bob     a4       30
147    Bob     a5       -8
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works

```
library(dplyr)


Name=c("Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob")
cluster=c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a4", "a5", "a5")
score=c(30,30,-28,-38,30,-8,30)
yourdf<-data.frame(Name,cluster,score)

yourdf %>%
  group_by(Name,cluster) %>%
  filter(score == min(score))

   Name cluster score
1 Steve      a1    30
2 Steve      a2   -38
3   Bob      a4    30
4   Bob      a5    -8
```

Answer (score 2):

And a simple `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(score = score[which.min(score)]), by = list(Name, cluster)]
#     Name cluster score
# 1: Steve      a1    30
# 2: Steve      a2   -38
# 3:   Bob      a4    30
# 4:   Bob      a5    -8
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect for `aggregate`.

```
> aggregate(score ~ Name + cluster, mydf, min)
#    Name cluster score
# 1 Steve      a1    30
# 2 Steve      a2   -38
# 3   Bob      a4    30
# 4   Bob      a5    -8
```

where `mydf` is your original data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach:

```
# Read in sample data
df<-read.table(text="
       Name   cluster   score
19     Steve   a1       30
51     Steve   a2       30
83     Steve   a2      -28
93     Steve   a2      -38
115    Bob     a4       30
147    Bob     a5       -8
179    Bob     a5       30", header=TRUE)

# order it
df_sorted <- df[with(df, order(Name, cluster, score)),]

# get rid of duplicated names and clusters, keeping the first,
# which will be the minimum score due to the sorting.

df_sorted[!duplicated(df_sorted[,c('Name','cluster')]), ]
#     Name cluster score
#115   Bob      a4    30
#147   Bob      a5    -8
#19  Steve      a1    30
#93  Steve      a2   -38
```